# How to ask a user a set of questions and store the answers

Tags: java

I'm making a text based adventure game. I'm trying to have the game choose a "class" for the player based on their answers to some questions. (E.g. if the player chooses sneaky or stealthy leaning answers then the game will assign them the "rogue" class which fits this type of person.

So far, I've created this method which I want to call later in the main program, and then based on what the return value is, I'll use another conditional statement to set the player class by calling a set method.

Here is my method so far. The way I'm heading, I will have a very very long chooseSpec method as I want at least maybe 10 questions. My question specifically is what is the most efficient way to write this out, and is doing it all in one method the right way to go?

```
public static int chooseSpec(Scanner in) {
    int war = 0; //counter for warrior class
    int rog = 0; //counter for rogue class
    int mag = 0; //counter for magic class
    int choice; //users choice, a number between 1 and 3.

    System.out.println("While out hunting, you come across a deer which has been badly mauled by a wolf. What do you do?" + "\n" +
                       "1. Draw your dagger and end it's suffering" + "\n" +
                       "2. Attempt to heal it with a herbal concoction, knowing it may not work." + "\n" +
                       "3. Leave it, and allow nature to take it's course.");
    choice = in.nextInt(); 

    switch (choice) {
        case 1: 
            war += 1;
            break;

        case 2:
            mag += 1;
            break;
        case 3:
            rog +=1;
    } 
    return choice;
}
```

Comment: this is an implementation flavory, is not a technical problem, please google ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already and take a look at [ask]. Anyway, I think you should look more into object-oriented programming (OOP). Look into [classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html) and [collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). You can make a class out of anything. For starters, maybe try to make a class called `Question` containing all information related to a question.

Comment: Also, if you have questions about *software design*, those are better suited for http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. And if you're looking to get feedback on your code, you can try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store all Questions and answers inside an object. That way, you can mix the answers for each question, currently choosing always 1 will guarantee same answer.

Secondly it will allow you to add any number of answers per question and even mix their order each time you are starting your game.

It's also good to use more java abstraction here:

```
public ClassType chooseSpec(List<Question> questions, Scanner in) {

     List<ClassType> selectedAnswers = new ArrayList<>(questions.size());
      // iterate over all your questions
    for(Question question: questions) {
        // print question and all answers
        System.out.println(question.getQuestion() + "\n"
                + question.getAnswers().stream().map(Answer::getQuestion)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));

        int choice = in.nextInt();
        if(choice >= question.getAnswers().size()){
          // check if answer is within the scope
          throw IllegalArgumentException("There are only "+question.getAnswers() +" answers");
        }
        // add selected answer type to global result list 
        selectedAnswers.add(question.getAnswers().get(choice-1).getClassType());
    }

    return findMostPolularClass(selectedAnswers);
}

private ClassType findMostPolularClass(List<ClassType> selectedAnswers){
    // might be too fancy, but it will find most frequent answer
    Map<ClassType, Long> occurences = selectedAnswers.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e, Collectors.counting()));
    return occurences.entrySet().stream()
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue)).get().getKey();
 }
```

Holds question and all answers:

```
static class Question {

    private final String question;
    private final List<Answer> answers;

    public Question(String question, List<Answer> answers) {
        this.question = question;
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }
}
```

Each answer defined the Answer text, and to which class it belongs best

```
class Answer {

    private final String question;
    private final ClassType classType;
    // static constructors, help to work with this model
    public static Answer mageAnswer(String question) {
        return new Answer(question, ClassType.MAGE);
    }

    public static Answer wariorAnswer(String question) {
        return new Answer(question, ClassType.WARIOR);
    }

    private Answer(String question, ClassType classType) {
        this.question = question;
        this.classType = classType;
    }

    public ClassType getClassType() {
        return classType;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
}
```

// Store all your classes here, it's more readable, than remembering numbers:)

```
enum ClassType {
    MAGE, WARIOR, ARCHER
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store all your questions in a collection. Like arraylist . Say you have 10 questions, this method shall be called in a foreach loop iterating over questions arraylist. In this way your method will be reused .

Answer (score 0):

From your requirements you want to deal with three different `Professions`:

- Warrior
- Rogue
- Mage

Those professions do not hold any state and new instance are not constructed dynamically. Hence an `Enumeration` would be a good candidate to represent them:

```
public enum Profession {
    WARRIOR,
    ROGUE,
    MAGE;
}
```

Next you ask the player to choose an`Answer` which is associated with 1. a `Profession` and 2. with a `Token`, the input you read from the keyboard:

```
public class Answer {

    public static Answer of(Profession profession, String token, String description) {
        return new Answer(description, profession, token);
    }

    private final String description;
    private final Profession profession;
    private final String token;

    public Answer(String description, Profession profession, String token) {
        this.description = requireNonNull(description);
        this.profession = requireNonNull(profession);
        this.token = requireNonNull(token);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Profession getProfession() {
        return this.profession;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public boolean isMatch(String token) {
        return this.token.equals(token);
    }
}
```

What you want to do with an `Answer` is:

- rendering it to the player.
- check if the token obtained from the player matches the token an `Answer` is associated with.
- and construct an `Answer` in a readable form.

`Answers` are part of `Questions` which do not hold state or are created dynamically. Once again an `Enumeration` would represent them well:

```
public enum Question {

    MAULED_DEER("While out hunting, you come across a deer which has been badly mauled by a wolf. What do you do?",
        Answer.of(WARRIOR, "1", "Draw your dagger and end it's suffering."),
        Answer.of(ROGUE, "2", "Attempt to heal it with a herbal concoction, knowing it may not work."),
        Answer.of(MAGE, "3", "Leave it, and allow nature to take it's course.")),

    GAME_DEVELOPMENT("While playing games you decided to develop your very own. Which language do you choose?",
            Answer.of(MAGE, "a", "OOD with Java."),
            Answer.of(WARRIOR, "b", "OOD and FP using Scala."),
            Answer.of(ROGUE, "c", "Pure FP with Haskel."));

    private final String description;
    private final List<Answer> answers;

    Question(String description, Answer... answers) {
        this.description = description;
        this.answers = Arrays.asList(answers);
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public Set<Answer> getMatches(String token) {
        return answers.stream()
                .filter(answer -> answer.isMatch(token))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

`Questions` must be:

- rendered together with their `Answers`.
- should determine which `Answers` do match a given token (obtained from the player).

But you are about to ask the player many `Questions` and want to track which `Answers` he gave. More precisely, the `Profession` you associated with an `Answer`. And you like to track the current score for each `Profession`:

```
public class Scores {

    private Map<Profession, AtomicInteger> scores = new HashMap<Profession, AtomicInteger>() {{
        for (Profession profession : Profession.values()) {
            put(profession, new AtomicInteger());
        }
    }};

    private int max = 0;

    public void incrementIf(boolean isTrue, Profession profession) {
        if (isTrue) {
            int score = scores.get(profession).incrementAndGet();
            max = Math.max(max, score);
        }
    }

    public Set<Profession> getWinners() {
        return Arrays.stream(Profession.values())
                .filter(profession -> scores.get(profession).get() == max)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

The responsibility of the type `Scores` is determine if and for which `Profession` to increment a score. Finally it should calculate the `Winners` of the inquiry:

```
public class Inquiry {

    public Set<Profession> obtainChoice(Scanner scanner) {
        Scores scores = new Scores();
        for (Question question : Question.values()) {
            String token = ask(question, scanner);
            question.getAnswers().forEach(answer ->
                    scores.incrementIf(answer.isMatch(token), answer.getProfession()));
        }
        return scores.getWinners();
    }

    private String ask(Question question, Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println(question.getDescription());
        question.getAnswers().forEach(answer ->
                System.out.println(answer.getToken() + ") " + answer.getDescription()));
        do {
            String token = scanner.nextLine();
            for (Answer answer : question.getAnswers()) {
                if (token.equals(answer.getToken())) {
                    return token;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Try again and select a valid answer please!");
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

The last piece of the puzzle missing is the application itself, which triggers the inquiry:

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            Set<Profession> choices = new Inquiry().obtainChoice(scanner);
            if (choices.size() == 1) {
                System.out.println("You are a true " + choices.iterator().next());
            } else {
                System.out.println("You havn't found your path yet and hence must choose between:");
                choices.forEach(profession -> System.out.println(" - " + profession));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This design strives to be `readable`and `extendable` so you could change things easily.

Have fun!